# error: No such schema 'com.canonical.desktop.interface'

Tags: overlay-scrollbars

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

I want to return a standard(old) scroll bar.

```
olga@olga:~$ gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
No such schema 'com.canonical.desktop.interface'
```

Can someone please suggest, **how do I get the standart scroll bar?**

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars set to false shows no arrows in several cases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190970/ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars-set-to-false-shows-no-arrows-in-several-cases?rq=1)

I took the decision that suggested @gh403

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution you are trying to do is suitable for Ubuntu versions 12.10 and not for 12.04 LTS.

If you would like to have the old scroll bar in Ubuntu 12.04 then you can do it by installing Ubuntu tweak. Here is the way to do it.

open your terminal with CTRL+ALT+T then type as

```
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/126356445/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.3-1%7Eprecise1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-tweak_0.8.3-1%7Eprecise1_all.deb
```

It will installs Ubuntu Tweak in your system. Then open it and click at tweaks TAB and there you can find your desired option.

Look at the image for more clarification,[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just reinstall back:

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar*
```